# PHP Unable to load dynamic library "libMagickWand"

Tags: php, imagick

This is an error I've received from multiple projects on live servers, but not localhost.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Core Warning
>
> Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/imagick.so' - libMagickWand.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> Filename: Unknown
>
> Line Number: 0
>
> Backtrace:

I have never used Imagick (libMagickWand) and none of the projects where I've received this error have I required functionality that Imagick offers, but for whatever reason I still get these errors. It's interfering with my scripts working properly. In this particular case, the error is appearing in a JSON formatted database select.

Some times the error appears, other times it doesn't, but when it does it causes my scripts that rely on that file containing JSON to not work. Refreshing is the only cure, but obviously that's not a permanent fix, not even a temporary one. I've googled it and all I can find is threads discussing how to install the library.

Any help in removing this error would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either:

- one of the ini files that you your live servers are using contains `extension=imagick.so`

or

- You've managed to compile PHP against Imagick but then deleted the ImageMagick library from the system.

Either way, you need to talk to whoever manages your server and find out why Imagick is trying to be loaded.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I'll speak with my host.